# How to figure out rejected account from an EDI Transactions

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions, edi

I am totally new to EDI transaction. I am trying to figure out when we send an enrollment request of a new customer to ISO, how to figure out if the reqest was accepted or rejected from EDI transaction.

The EDI transaction in an entry in EDI_TRANSACTION table. Basically it contains the complete response but it does not explicitly says if the request was rejected or accepted.

According to EDI standards, Abbreviation codes are use instead of language. An example is here [enter link description here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8ph9U2_mZNYJ%3awww.nationalgridus.com/shared_content/ebt/non_html/ma_error_codes.xls%20edi%20codes%20ma&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

For me, not all enrollment transaction carry the above codes. In fact the majority of them are blank and some of them are A13, A77 etc.

AT this point I am working at the database level. I need to pull rejections in a report (SQL Query).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download EDI Notepad here:  https://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi/edi-notepad

Open the raw EDI using the EDI Notepad and it will show you what the codes mean.  Also - contact your trading partner and see if you can't get a spec from them outlining what codes they are using in their implementation guide. Looking at the raw EDI using that tool will help you.